# Target monorepo root directory in jest config within monorepo package

Tags: jestjs, monorepo

I have the following file structure in my monorepo

```
monorepo
 ┣ node_modules
 ┣ packages
 ┃ ┣ package-1
 ┃ ┃ ┗ jest.config.js
 ┃ ┣ package-2
 ┃ ┃ ┗ jest.config.js
 ┃ ┣ package-3
 ┃ ┃ ┗ jest.config.js
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ jest.base.config.js
```

In the monorepo root I have the file `jest.base.config.js` which contains

```
module.exports = {
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?|@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome|d3-.*|internmap)/)',
  ],
};
```

Then in each packages `jest.config.js` I imported the `jest.base.config` and export it with any overrides, like so

```
const baseConfig = require('../../jest.base.config');

module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/cypress/'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}', '!src/**/*.style.{ts,js}'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockSVG.js',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|pdf)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockFile.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  globals: {
    __WEB__: true,
    google: {},
  },
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
};
```

However, there is an issue with one of the packages `@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor` [(Issue Here)](https://github.com/uiwjs/react-textarea-code-editor/issues/111#issue-1204328945) that needs a mapper, so trying to map it to a common js file, by adding it as a property in the `moduleNameMapper` property in the `jest.config.js` file.

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  ...
  '@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js',
},
```

This works on a regular repository I have, but the issue here is `<rootDir>/node_modules` is targeting `./packages/package-1/node_modules` and not `./node_modules` on the root of the monorepo as that is where the `@uiw` directory resides.

Now, I know I can change the `rootDir` to be `rootDir: './../../',` but that throws off all other references to `rootDir`

I tried

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  ...
  '@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor': '../../node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js',
},
```

Which should target `./node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js`

But that gives me the following error

```
Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module @uiw/react-textarea-code-editor mapped as:
    ../../node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js.
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/@uiw\/react-textarea-code-editor/": "../../node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
```

Is there a more elegant solution than changing the `rootDir` value?

Comment: Are you ok using `rehype@11.0.0`?

Comment: I run into similar issues with jest and other module packages, mainly ones within a the same monorepo. I think it's a bug in jest to be honest. Their support for ESM is still unstable.

Comment: It is a bit of a sledge hammer, but you could probably do `transformIgnorePatterns: ['!/node_modules/']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able use `path.resolve`?

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  '@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor': path.resolve(
     __dirname, 
    '../../node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js'
  ),
},
```

or a relative path to `<root>`

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  '@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor': '<rootDir>/../../node_modules/@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor/dist/editor.js'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [linked to issue](https://github.com/uiwjs/react-textarea-code-editor/issues/111), I believe [this comment](https://github.com/uiwjs/react-textarea-code-editor/issues/111#issuecomment-1099074132) correctly identifies the problem. Once the maintainers of `@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor` decided to use a version of `rehype` that only supports ESM, they should have removed their support of CJS in the next major release.

If you are ok with downgrading your `@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor` version you can `npm i @uiw/react-textarea-code-editor@1.3.1` which is the most recent version that relies on a CommonJS version of `rehype`.

Alternatively, if you are ok mixing your current version of`@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor` with a different version of `rehype` and use a package manager that supports transitive dependency resolution, for example `resolutions` for `yarn` or `overrides` for `npm`, then you can downgrade to `rehype@11.0.0` the most recent version using CommonJS.

For example, using `npm`:

```json
  "overrides": {
    "rehype": "11.0.0"
  }
```